# phpMyAdmin 5.2.1 not compatible with php 8.1.0 error message with wamp server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using WAMP server I need update my current php version 7.4 to php 8.1 and I did it as well. now I need update my phpmyadmin to 5.2.1 and I did upgrade manually it. Now in my localhost says `phpMyAdmin 5.2.1 not compatible with php 8.1.0` then how could I fix this problem? Documents says phpmyadmin 5.2.1 compatibility with PHP compatible with PHP 7.2 and newer.

I need good solutions for this matter

Comment: Is there a reason you're using PHP 8.1 rather than 8.2.1? I use 8.2.1 and phpMyAdmin 5.2.0 without any problems.

Comment: same error message `phpMyAdmin 6.0 not compatible with php 8.1.0`

Comment: Where and how exactly are you seeing that error message?

Comment: @ADyson in my phpMyAdmin in the localhost

Comment: You mean on the phpmyadmin home page? Can we have a screenshot?

Comment: @ADyson yes please see https://ibb.co/K7GmHPh

Comment: That looks like it might be more of an issue of that Wampserver status dashboard. Have you tried to actually _access_ your phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @CBroe acctually with php 7.4 it is working fine. but I upgrated my php 7.4 to 8.1 then this problem occured

Comment: `in my phpMyAdmin in the localhost`...that's not a picture of phpmyadmin. That's your wamp dashboard. As CBroe says, have you actually tried to load phpmyadmin itself?

Comment: @ADyson yes when try to load phpmyadmin it got following error `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) PHP/8.1.0 Server at localhost Port 80`

Comment: Well that's a filesystem permission error probably...very unlikely it has to do with the PHP version directly

Comment: Then how it do?

Comment: How to set filesystem permissions, you mean?

Comment: _I need update my phpmyadmin to 5.2.1_ ___and I did upgrade manually___ WHY MANUALLY????. Look at [The WAMPServer backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and pick the versions of Anything and Everything in WAMPServer and use the pre-prepared installs, and get it right. The backup repo is easier to navigate than SourceForge and is usually updated quicker

Comment: Try installing (using the Backup Repo download of) phpMyAdmin 5.2.1. If phpMyAdminV6 is not in there yet, then there is a reason! Oto is very good at providing up to the minute releases of ALL the WAMPServer component that are fit to use

Comment: I got this error on Wampserver and set my php version back to 7.3.5 and was still getting the error. My browser had cached it, I did ctrl-F5 and then it started working. The wampserver message is still showing, even after restarting wampserver